# How to sync multiple tables asynchronously in azure offline sync in android

Tags: java, android, azure, asynchronous

I am working on azure-android which uses offline sync facility. I have to sync multiple tables. Currently i am doing this like below. For each table i call pull method, currently what i see is each one gets pulled one by one. I would like do do this in async way also i need to wait for all tables to sync.

```
   public void syncAsync(){
        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {

                        mItemsTable.pull(mPullQuery_Items).get();
                        mCustomerTable.pull(mPullQuery_Customer).get();
                        mSalesTable.pull(mPullQuery_Sales).get();
         //Few more tables to pull.                            
                    } catch (Exception exception) {
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally {
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            }.execute();
        } else {
    //error
        }
    }
```

I see that Microsoft uses ListneableFuture and tried to read some info from

[This link](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained)

I see this code sample in the link

List> queries;
// ***The queries go to all different data centers, but we want to wait until they're all done or failed.***

```
ListenableFuture<List<QueryResult>> successfulQueries = Futures.successfulAsList(queries);

Futures.addCallback(successfulQueries, callbackOnSuccessfulQueries);
```

I am trying to change my code like above but i am not able to understand how to do this. i would like to wait until they are all done (all table pulled) and need a list of success or failure. Since i am beginer in Java finding it bit difficult to understand as how to modify.

Comment: Now I solved the problem of async sync like this, just call pull method without doing get and save the listenableFuture object returned by pull. Once all the tables pull is called. call get on each listenable object. at this time it will block till it finishes pull.

Comment: Still i am not sure of successfulAsList usage. can any one help me with that?

Comment: The description for `successfulAsList` said  "Returns a ListenableFuture whose value is a list containing the values of each of the successful input futures, in order. The values corresponding to failed or cancelled futures are replaced with null." It seems to be like DB transaction operation.

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT i understan what it returns but i am not sure what is the argument to give in successfulAsList function as per my code shown above

Comment: I post the content for `successfulAsList`. It's too long as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

@Nasir 
The argument given in function `successfulAsList` is either ListenableFuture type varargs or a list containing the ListenableFuture type values, please refer to http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#successfulAsList(com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture...).

So you need to wrap the process `mXxxTable.pull().get()` up a object implement the interface `Callable` as the argument of the function `submit` of interface `ListeningExecutorService` to get the `ListenableFuture` Object for one of the varargs (or list) for successfulAsList.

There is a test demo below as a reference. And The blog http://codingjunkie.net/google-guava-futures/ explain more details.

```
public void should_test_furture() throws Exception {
    ListeningExecutorService service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));

    ListenableFuture future1 = service.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
        public Integer call() throws InterruptedException {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("call future 1.");
            return 1;
        }
    });

    ListenableFuture future2 = service.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
        public Integer call() throws InterruptedException {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("call future 2.");
  //       throw new RuntimeException("----call future 2.");
            return 2;
        }
    });

    final ListenableFuture allFutures = Futures.successfulAsList(future1, future2);

    final ListenableFuture transform = Futures.transform(allFutures, new AsyncFunction<List<Integer>, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public ListenableFuture apply(List<Integer> results) throws Exception {
            return Futures.immediateFuture(String.format("success future:%d", results.size()));
        }
    });

    Futures.addCallback(transform, new FutureCallback<Object>() {

        public void onSuccess(Object result) {
            System.out.println(result.getClass());
            System.out.printf("success with: %s%n", result);
        }

        public void onFailure(Throwable thrown) {
            System.out.printf("onFailure%s%n", thrown.getMessage());
        }
    });

    System.out.println(transform.get());
}
```